# How to set a fixed number of ticks on QwtPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm having some trouble with `QwtPlot` ticks.

The X axis of my `QwtPlot` is this:

[image]

I'm setting the **AxisMaxMajor** to 24:

```
dataPlot->setAxisMaxMajor(QwtPlot::xBottom, 24);
```

But it does not solve my problem.

I need exactly 23 ticks (1~23) to represent each hour of the day. How can I do that?

Qwt 6.1.0

Qt 5.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When needing date/time related ticks you need to use `QwtDateScaleEngine`. Scale engines based on the decimal system won't come up if with something in 1-24.

If the `QwtDateScale` classes does not fit for your use case you have the option to set the ticks manually ( `QwtPlot::setAxisScaleDiv()` ).

In case you have no control over the axis ranges ( f.e because of zooming ) the final fallback solution is to implement your own type of `QwtScaleEngine`. This is easier as it sounds, as it simply means returning a tick at every hour for a given range.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe. I do not have control over the axis range (because of zooming), then I think I need to implement my own type of `QwtScaleEngine` like you said. Can you provide a simple example of how can I do that?